# Java allocation : allocating objects from a pre-existing/allocated pool

Tags: java, memory, allocation

In a Java program when it is necessary to allocate thousands of similar-size objects, it would be better (in my mind) to have a "pool" (which is a single allocation) with reserved items that can be pulled from when needed. This single large allocation wouldn't fragment the heap as much as thousands of smaller allocations.

Obviously, there isn't a way to specifically point an object reference to an address in memory (for its member fields) to set up a pool. Even if the new object referenced an area of the pool, the object itself would still need to be allocated. How would you handle many allocations like this without resorting to native OS libraries?

Comment: What does your application do? what is the purpose of this swarm of objects?

Comment: Load vectors from an inconceivably large vector map of the world, containing vectors for coastlines, rivers, countries, states, other boundaries and area data (such as forestry, economic data, etc) - mind you this vector data is extremely high resolution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using the [Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) library.

That said, unless I had proof the JVM wasn't doing what I needed, I'd probably hold off on optimizing object creation.

Comment: What worries me is that all of these allocations will only be used temporarily, and the JVM will constantly be allocating new memory, and collect countless objects for garbage collection. If it were allocated from a pool, I wouldn't need to worry about JVM constantly dealing with such a huge volume of garbage.

Comment: This library you referred me to might do the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: @WilliamtheCoderer Yep, I totally understand the potential issues. Object instantiation is *really* fast; I'm just saying I'd rather see the issue manifest before throwing things at it. OTOH, it's pretty easy to use, so it probably doesn't matter ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it. Unless you have done a lot of testing and analysis on the actual code being run and know that it is a problem with garbage collection and that the JVM isn't doing a good enough job, spend your time elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building an application, where a predictable response time is very important, then pooling of objects, no matter how small they are will pay you dividends. Again, pooling is also a factor of how big of a data set you are trying to pool and how much physical memory your machine has.

There is ample [proof on the web](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/10/recycling-objects-to-improve.html) that shows that object pooling, no matter how small the objects are, is beneficial for application performance.

There are two levels of pooling you could do:

- Pooling of the basic objects such as Vectors, which you retrieve from the pool each time you have to use the vector to form a map or such.
- Have the higher level composite objects pooled, which are most commonly used, pooled.

This is generally an application design decision.

Also, in a multi-threaded application, you would like to be sensitive about how many different threads are going to be allocating and returning to the pool. You certainly do not want your application to be bogged down by contention - especially if you are dealing with thousands of objects at the same time.

Comment: good info. I used pooling in C++, but it's so much simpler to implement a pool with pointers. I'm slowly learning how to deal without pointers, even though I liked using them better.

Comment: [apache commons pooling](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) is usually where all Java programmers start when looking for an object pool implementation. This is a very generic implementation and you can come up with your own in not much time either.

Answer (score 0):

@Dave and Casey, you don't need any proof to show that contiguous memory layout improves Cache efficiency, which is the major bottleneck in most OOP apps that need high performance but follow a "too idealistic" OOP-design trajectory.

People often think of the GC as the culprit causing low performance in high performance Java applications and after fixing it, just leave it at that, without actually profiling memory-behavior of the application. Note though that un-cached memory instructions are inherently more expensive than arithmetic instructions (and are getting more and more expensive due to the memory access <-> computation gap). So if you care about performance, you should certainly care about memory management.

Cache-aware, or more general, data-oriented programming, is the key to achieving high performance in many kinds of applications, such as games, or mobile apps (to reduce power consumption).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122696/what-is-data-oriented-programming) is a SO thread on DOP.

[Here](http://research.scee.net/files/presentations/gcapaustralia09/Pitfalls_of_Object_Oriented_Programming_GCAP_09.pdf) is a slideshow from the Sony R&D department that shows the usefulness of DOP as applied to a playstation game (high performance required).

So how to solve the problem that Java, does not, in general allow you to allocate a chunk of memory? My guess is that when the program is just starting, you can assume that there is very little internal fragmentation in the already allocated pages. If you now have a loop that allocates thousands or millions of objects, they will probably all be as contiguous as possible. Note that you only need to make sure that consecutive objects stretch out over the same cacheline, which in many modern systems, is only 64 bytes. Also, take a look at the DOP slides, if you really care about the (memory-) performance of your application.

In short: Always allocate multiple objects at once (increase temporal locality of allocation), and, if your GC has defragmentation, run it beforehand, else try to reduce such allocations to the beginning of your program.

I hope, this is of some help,
-Domi

PS: @Dave, the commons pool library does not allocate objects contiguously. It only keeps track of the allocations by putting them into a reference array, embedded in a stack, linked list, or similar.